# IF statement looping(repeating) multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am running nested if statement but what I am getting is multiple execution of the functions inside the if statements. I could really appreciate any help.

I have tried using only 'if' without else but it worsened. That led me to go back to my first code but this time edited some parts. Still the problem persists.

This is the code which has the problem. The alert 'Please fill in the recipient!' is displayed multiple times. Still the success ajax post function displays multiple times etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sending').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if( ($('#receiver_id1').val() == '0') && 
            ($('#receiver_id2').val() == '0') && 
            ($('#receiver_id3').val() == '0'))
        {
            alert("Please fill in the recipient!");
            return false;
        } else {
            if($.trim($("#message").val()) == '') {
                alert("You cannot send an empty message.");
                return false;
            } else {
                if($('#subject').val() == '') {
                    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure to send a message without a subject?");
                    if( retVal == true ) {
                        //Variables declaration and ajax post function.
                        //On success, alert message 'message sent'
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    //Variables declaration and ajax post function.
                    //On success, alert message 'message sent'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

if the conditions are met I have an ajax post function that sends data to a php file which it does only that data is sent multiple times.

Comment: You could condense that logic (if field is not empty OR person confirmed it's OK to be empty) {ajax post}

Comment: The above code is a summary. The full code has ajax post function that should be executed if the conditions are true.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the OR condition, i.e. `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: How do you know that you're "getting is multiple execution of the functions inside the if statements"?

Comment: @James I tried that but returned and error on the ajax post. The $('#subject').val()  returns an error if the field is empty.

Comment: @Some. Inside the if statements I had place alert messages which are displayed multiple times.

Comment: The OR logic returns false even when one of the fields is filled. That is not the expected result @terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things I can suggest you, change to below to make your code more readable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sending').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var makeAjaxCall = false;
        if( ($('#receiver_id1').val() == '0') && 
            ($('#receiver_id2').val() == '0') && 
            ($('#receiver_id3').val() == '0'))
        {
            alert("Please fill in the recipient!");
            return false;
        }

        if($.trim($("#message").val()) == '') {
                alert("You cannot send an empty message.");
                return false;
         }

        if($('#subject').val() == '') {
         makeAjaxCall = confirm("Are you sure to send a message without a subject?");
        }
        else {makeAjaxCall = true}

        if(makeAjaxCall){
        // do your ajax call

        }
        /* return false in end */
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. cheers!! when someone answers your question and it works. you can upvote the answer, a gentleman's gesture. @sam